# Looking for an automatic conversion tool (Informix -> MariaDB)

Tags: mariadb, informix

Does any one know about a tool that could automatically translate any Informix SQL query to MariaDB SQL queries ?
So far, I have been looking at:

> http://www.sqlines.com/online  => doesn't work
>
> https://www.toolsverse.com/faq/index.html  => no final solution
>
> https://dbconvert.com/ => no informix
>
> http://www.ispirer.com/products/informix-to-mysql-migration => nothing obvious
>
> http://info.swissql.com/ => product no supported anymore

Any hint really welcome !

Comment: On *nix? Try sed and awk!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench has conversion tools for a number of other databases.

Answer (score 0):

SQLines is actually not that bad.  Use the non-online version.  The tricky part is getting the Informix driver to connect properly.  You can configure ODBC to connect by installing the appropriate driver, but the tricky part is convincing SQLines that the driver is available in the path variable.

You can get the Informix driver without having to sign your life away here: https://www.ciscounitytools.com/Applications/CxN/InformixODBC/InformixODBC.html

Informix is really ornery about the locales.  You need to set them properly or it won't connect.  It's what tells informix who will convert the type information.

When you're setting up an ODBC connection, Service refers to the port number that Informix is listening on.  Protocol (for us) was onsoctcp (Connection tab).  We had to use DB_Locale: en_US.57372 and Client_Locale: en_US.57372 (Environment tab).  You'll likely have to flip back and forth between the tabs in the ODBC setup a few times.